# Remove all characters between two other characters (keeping the other characters)

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I know this question has been asked multiple times in different ways, but I can't find a solution where I would replace the text between some "borders" while keeping the borders.

```
input <- "this is my 'example'"
change <- "test"
```

And now I want to replace everything between teh single quotes with the value in `change`.

Expected output would be `"this is my 'test'`

I tried different variants of:

```
stringr::str_replace(input, "['].*", change)
```

But it doesn't work. E.g. the one above gives `"this is my test"`, so it doesn't have the single quotes anymore.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

And this way?

```
input <- "this is my 'example'"
change <- "test"

stringr::str_replace(input, "(?<=').*?(?=')", change)
```

**(?<=')** ← look the character before is a **'** without catching it.
**.** ← catch any characters but as less as possible. To covert a case like "this is my **'example' did you see 'it'**"
**(?=')** ← look the character following is a **'** without catching it.

↓ Tested here ↓

[ideone](https://ideone.com/tVPool)

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```r
stringr::str_replace_all(input, "'[^']*'", paste0("'", change, "'"))
gsub("'[^']*'", paste0("'", change, "'"), input)
```

Or, you may also capture the apostophes and then use backreferences, but that would look uglier (cf. `gsub("(')[^']*(')", paste0("\\1",change,"\\2"), input)`).

See the [R demo online:](https://ideone.com/toONOf)

```r
input <- "this is my 'example'"
change <- "test"
stringr::str_replace_all(input, "'[^']*'", paste0("'", change, "'"))
gsub("'[^']*'", paste0("'", change, "'"), input)
```

Output:

```
[1] "this is my 'test'"
[1] "this is my 'test'"
```

**Note**: if your `change` variable contains a backslash, it must be doubled to avoid issues:

```r
stringr::str_replace_all(input, "'[^']*'", paste0("'", gsub("\\", "\\\\", change, fixed=TRUE), "'"))
gsub("'[^']*'", paste0("'", gsub("\\", "\\\\", change, fixed=TRUE), "'"), input)
```

Comment: Thanks, but this gives an error: `Error in "'" + change : non-numeric argument to binary operator`, I guess it's because of the + signs.

Comment: @deschen Just fixed this. Was playing with a different language.

Comment: @deschen I hoped that `change` does not contain substrings like `\1` or `\2` that need to be treated literally. In case they do, see the note I added at the bottom. See [this demo](https://ideone.com/DsLDu5) to better understand what I mean.

Comment: Why are you using `gsub()` if the OP only expects one occurrence in single quotes?

Comment: Thanks. It works now, although I decided for this ozther solution from @wace since I don't need to do teh pasting of my `change` with quotes.

Comment: And no, the text won't contain substrings like \1 or \2.

Comment: @deschen Note that  in case of replacing multiple substrings, `(?<=').*?(?=')` won't work. You must consume the quotes in order to match the right strings between quotes, and not the strings between quoted substrings.

Comment: Ok, but in my case there will just be one string/substring. It actually is a written file path in single quotes that I want to replace by sth. else, and I won‘t have a case where there are several things put into quotes.  But understood that the accepted solution won‘t work if there are multiple such strings.

Answer (score 3):

Using `sub()` we can try:

```r
input <- "this is my 'example'"
change <- "test"
output <- sub("'.*?'", paste0("'", change, "'"), input)
output

[1] "this is my 'test'"
```